# How to set the width of html element having position as fixed

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="ui-datatable-scrollable-view" style="
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
">
        <div class="ui-widget-header ui-datatable-scrollable-header" style="position:fixed;top:50px">
         
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a div element which is stick on the top of the page. I have given the css as

```css
width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
```

But it is not taking the width.

I tried several ways to do that.
I tried making the parent div as position:relative but that is not working;

I think my element is taking the width equal to the width of screen.I tried giving the fixed width to it to fit the required size. But on change of screeen size it won't work proper.
I want it to take the width of its parent.

Comment: percentage width refers to it's parent element width

Comment: where is the full code? Your snippet is lacking :)

Comment: use `width: 100vw;` then its relative to the viewport

Comment: Please show the html code also

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem and provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have added the html code snippet. In that I want my inner div to be as fixed and width =width of parent div

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using your css and it works for me

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 2;
 background-color: black;
}
```

Check if your html and body elements have a width of 100%

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/athapliyal/pen/VzqyBX

Comment: This does not provide an useful answer, please consider adding a comment to the question instead

Comment: I want a child div having position as fixed that will inherit the 100% width of its parent

Answer (score 0):

```css
#test {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
```

If you provide the width as percentage it is relative to the parent of the div, so you could define the parent with a width of 100% to make it working. To provide you an example we would need more code.

So the other solution is by defining the width with `100vw`.
`1vw` = 1% of viewport (window) width.

This way it will be relative to the viewport and doesn´t care about the parent.

For the height you can use: `vh` (Viewport height)

Comment: If you need more code to answer the question, please add a comment. This answer is based on a guess, and does not provide helpful information

Comment: @MatthiasS. It does, vw will work as a solution in every case he could have. I explained him why his actual code could go wrong and gave him an example how to make it 100% working, for me this is an usefull answer.

Comment: Actually my fixed element is taking the width of viewport when i give width as 100%.But I want it to take the width of its parent div

Comment: @AshishBisht Than add the css code of your parent too please

Comment: @Doomenik Yes..I have tried giving the width and position to the parent element too.But its not working.  And I can't use 'vh' because i dont want to depend of viewport size.As I have a collapsable side bar, so it should be responsive for that too..Better if I could inherit the parents width

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the width is in fact `100%`, however since you did not set a height, it appears invisible.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  width: 800px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 600px;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  width: inherit; height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: yes..but I want child to inherit the width of parent